# How to change text color of autocomplete input box (GMaps API v3)

Tags: css, google-maps-api-3

I used the code of a beginners turtorial (by Mano Marks / Google) about the autocomplete method of GMaps. Now everything works fine, however I don't know how to change the color of the suggested strings in the autocomplete box that is adjusted to my input-field
I want to do that because the default color seems to be white!!??

Does somebody  know how to change that color! Thanks a lot.
Here is the code:

```
HTML:
Suche:<input type="text" id="autocomplete" size="40" />
......
JS:
//Autocomplete

 var acOptions = {
    types:['establishment'],

};
 var autocomplete =
new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('autocomplete'),acOptions);
autocomplete.bindTo('bounds',map);
var ac_iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

 var ac_marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map
 });

 google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete,'place_changed',function(){
   ac_iw.close();
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
  if(place.geometry.viewport){
      map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
  }
  else{
      map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
      map.setZoom(17);
  }

 ac_marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
 ac_iw.setContent('<strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br/>');
 ac_iw.open(map,ac_marker);
 google.maps.event.addListener(ac_marker,'click',function(){
    ac_iw.open(map,ac_marker);
  });

 });
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no particular text-color set for the suggestions. But however, you may use the CSS-selector

```
.pac-container *
```

... to apply a custom style.

Comment: Does that mean that white text is a default value of the gmaps autocomplete object??

Comment: That means that the white text-color must either be a result of your author-CSS(the CSS defined for your page) or of the user-CSS(the default-styles defined for your browser)

Comment: Ah, thanks, that autocomplete box seems to enherit the text-color from the body tag.